# Partial derivative operator expansion

Tags: multivariable-calculus, partial-derivative

Expand
$$
(h\frac{\partial}{\partial t}+hf\frac{\partial}{\partial x})^3
$$
Where
$$
x'(t)=f(x,t)=f
$$
If this question is ridiculously hard to answer, at least tell me if this is correct
$$
(h\frac{\partial}{\partial t}+hf\frac{\partial}{\partial x})^2=h^2(\frac{\partial^2}{\partial x^2}+\frac{\partial f}{\partial t}\frac{\partial}{\partial x}+f\frac{\partial^2}{\partial t \partial x}+f\frac{\partial^2}{\partial x \partial t}+f^2\frac{\partial^2}{\partial x^2})
$$
And is this also correct with function g
$$
f\frac{\partial^2}{\partial t \partial x}g \neq f\frac{\partial^2}{\partial x \partial t}g
$$

Answer (score 0):

$$
(h\frac{\partial}{\partial t}+hf\frac{\partial}{\partial x})^3\\
\implies
h^3\frac{\partial^3}{\partial t^3}+3h^2\frac{\partial^2}{\partial t^2}hf\frac{\partial}{\partial x}+3h\frac{\partial}{\partial t}h^2f^2\frac{\partial^2}{\partial x^2}+h^3f^3\frac{\partial^3}{\partial x^3}
$$
I'll leave it to you to use the chain rule, and the given information.

Comment: This is incorrect. You "expanded" the expression as if it was a polynomial in commuting  variables. Differential operators with nonconstant coefficients do not commute in general.